# cannot load JDBC driver for MySQL datasource on WebLogic

Tags: mysql, jdbc, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I can't create a datasource for MySQL and WebLogic server 10.3 due to this error:

> Error: cannot load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I'm using the `http://localhost:7101/console` for creating datasource, not with xml descriptor.

Where can I place the require MySQLconnector jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the MySQL Connector JAR and put it in the /server/ext/jbdc directory.  I'd create a new directory called "mysql".

Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13737/third_party_drivers.htm) might help, too.

Comment: Your thanks are warm and wonderful, but you're supposed to accept and upvote correct answers here.